# Proper snowball analyzer configuration when using Grails Searchable Plugin

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable, compass-lucene

To improve stemming we want to switch from the default analyzer to snowball, however, having a lot of difficulty with the proper settings and would appreciate any help.  In

Environment: 
- Sun's Java 1.6.16
- Grails 1.2.2
- Searchable Plug-In 0.5.5

Config.groovy:
  Have tried both settings:

```
compassSettings = ['compass.engine.analyzer.stemmed.type': 'snowball',
                     'compass.engine.analyzer.stemmed.name': 'English']

compassSettings = ['compass.engine.analyzer.snowball.type': 'snowball',
                     'compass.engine.analyzer.snowball.name': 'English',
                     'compass.engine.analyzer.search.type': 'snowball',
                     'compass.engine.analyzer.search.name': 'English']
```

Search.groovy - The Invocation:

```
def searchResult = searchableService.search(params.q, withHighlighter: {
highlighter, index, sr 

  if (!sr.highlights) {
    sr.highlights = []
  }
  try {
         sr.highlights[index] = highlighter.fragments("content")[0..2].join(" ")
      } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
          sr.highlights[index] = highlighter.fragment("content")
      }
  })

  def suggestion = searchableService.suggestQuery(params.q)
  if (suggestion != params.q) {
      searchResult.suggestedQuery = suggestion
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting these settings in Searchable.groovy instead of Config.grovy?

In Searchable.groovy, I have:

```
    compassSettings = [
    'compass.engine.analyzer.default.type': 'snowball',
    'compass.engine.analyzer.default.name': 'English',
    'compass.engine.analyzer.search.type': 'snowball',
    'compass.engine.analyzer.search.name': 'English',
]
```

And that seems to work fine for me.